# How do I check if mentioned member is found?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I check if a mention is a mention

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!find')) {
    target = msg.mentions.members.first()
    if (!target) return msg.channel.send(`Member not found!`)
    msg.channel.send('Found!')
}
```

This was my code, I want to check if the mention is found cause the `if(!target)` only work with the null result.

Comment: We dont have access to the values. Post them. What is `console.log(msg.content, target)`?

Comment: What values? I have no `console.log(msg.content, target)` here

Comment: But you have `msg.content` and `target` as a variable. We cannot guess values, that defies logic, and logic is programming. What are its values? Read [mcve]

Comment: msg.content  is the same as message.content and target is equal to msg.mentions.members.first()

Comment: !find <@!804740405252849687>

Comment: I don't understand your question, `msg.mentions.members` will always return the Collection of mentioned members

Comment: I just solved it myself go down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code myself!!

The code was

```js
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!find')) {
    target = msg.mentions.members.first()
    if (!target) return msg.channel.send(`Member not found!`)
    msg.channel.send('Found!')
}
```

The solution is

```js
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!find')) {
    let target = msg.mentions.members.first()
    if (!target) return msg.channel.send(`Member not found!`)
    msg.channel.send('Found!')
}
```

I forgot to make a let, no problem Thx to @Elitzen and @Xorifelse for support